# How to use Asterisk action in C

Tags: c, asterisk

Is there a way to use asterisk AMI in c language? I want to get information about asterisk in its module using C language. I have configured manager.conf file.

Comment: You should ask one question per post, it'll help you get good answers

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Please take the .5 seconds to hover over his tag ... This is not a bad question, stop downvoting. It just needs refinement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMI is simple interface using tcp socket.

Sure you can use it from c.

You can get libs from this page:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+Examples